# Change label text based upon CurrentUICulture

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I've recently been tasked with localizing a small piece of software that my company created.  I've been able to create the resx file for the particular culture, and things are well and good.  Thing is, that there are roughly 50 or so labels/buttons/etc, that need to be changed. My question is, do I need to write in the code to set the text, or is there an easier way?  For instance,

`lblText.text = Resources.labelText`

for every single button/label.  Or is there a property in the button/label that I'm missing that would set it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the text directly with the form designer of visual studio. Just set the form's property `Localizable` to true and change the `Language` property to the one you want to translate. Then, every change you make will only be reflected in the language you selected

If you want more help, you can take a look at [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you.  This worked out brilliantly, and saved me loads of trouble.